# npm install react-router missing examples folder in repository?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, directory, react-router

When running `npm install react-router`, it installs [`react-router v1.0.3`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/v1.0.3) which contains an `examples` folder. However after running

```
cd node_modules/react-router
ls
```

the output is

```
CHANGES.md          README.md           es6                 npm-scripts
CONTRIBUTING.md     SPONSORS.md         lib                 package.json
LICENSE.md          docs                node_modules        umd
```

It's missing the `examples` folder! How do I get the `examples` from `npm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

When packages are distributed through NPM, the developers can choose what gets included. Since packages are intended to be used as *dependencies*, a lot things are often excluded as unnecessary bulk.

This is controlled by the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) property in `package.json` (and in an `.npmignore` file). If you look [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/package.json#L5) you can see that they have not included `examples` in the NPM distribution.

That said, NPM is not a good vehicle for example code, but GitHub is. Why not fetch the examples from there?

Comment: I never realized that `files` was like the opposite of `.npmignore`. Thanks for pointing that out.